# Thread safety due to no runtime allocation of memory, why?

Tags: memory-management, simulation, threads

I was [watching a presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xVN-qY78P4) related to the MuJoCo simulator (and other topics which were more relevant for the presentation itself) and at one moment in the presentation it is mentioned that MuJoCo has thread safety due to not having memory allocation in runtime.

Why is thread safety ensured because of this? Memory might not be allocated in runtime, but still various threads might try to access the same resource, no?

Answer (score 1):

They seem to believe that runtime memory allocation causes thread safety to be lost. But the only problem is that you need to synchronise allocation and deallocation of memory, so if two threads need the same memory at the same time, one allocates and the other waits until it has been allocated.

Once that memory is allocated you have the same problem as with fixed memory to keep your access to the memory thread safe.

Comment: That is what came to my mind, there isn't difference with the memory allocated in runtime one all the memory is allocated. In any case you will need to synchronize access.